# Differences between inference method and search method in constraint programming

Tags: constraint-programming

To solve a constraint problem, we can use **inference method** and/or **search method**. [Constraint Propagation. Christian Bessiere, 2006](http://www.math.unipd.it/~frossi/bessiere) states in the very beginning: Constraint propagation is a form of inference, not search.

From my understanding, the inference method is to reduce domain. What does search method mean in CP? Many materials mentioned that constraint problems can be solved with inference method alone. How could it be possible? (My thought: During the inference steps, we still have to loop over constraints, then I think it also does **searching** for constraint processing. No search method used here?)

Basically, this question is about how inference method are different from search method. How can I tell that a solution used inference method only or search method only or both? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify the difference between propagation and search :

Propagation : (also called Constraint Propagation, Filtering algorithms or inference methods) : Suppose we have the constraint $x+7 <= 9 $ such that the current domain of $x$ is $D(x) = {0,1,2,3,4} $, then one can infer that the values $3$ and $4$ should be removed. This process is called propagation. In general, each constraint C is associated to a propagator that, when invoked, look at the current domain of each variable in its scope and try to reduce them.

Search: Suppose now that we executed all the propagators of a given problem until no more filtering can occur. What a CP solver does, is to "branch" on a variable and assign it to a value, i.e. we decide to go to a new node in the search tree. The decision can indeed be a bad one, so we should be able to backtrack later and take another decision. This mechanism is called search, decision, branching.. and is usually performed using a heuristic.

State-of-the-art CP Solvers use the combination Search+Propagation (which can be seen as an improvement of DPLL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) ). Note also that when the solver starts propagation, it never stop until a fix-point is reached, i.e. in order to be sure that no more domain reduction can occur.

Comment: Is it that : for a search method, it is always every variable was assigned a value to determine? but for inference method, some variables may not get a value?

Comment: They are completely incomparable! when we say search, it is based on decisions that we make in order to explore the search tree. For that, we take one variable that is not yet assigned to a value, we decide (for example) to assign it to a given value of its domain and then we execute propagation, i.e. what can we infer given the current domain of the variables. If we reach a state where the decisions we took lead to a failure, we backtrack, undo all the actions done on the domains at a given level then take another decision.